# Htmx - Disable saving snapshot of the DOM with hx-push-url=true

Tags: browser-history, htmx

According to `Htmx` doc for [`hx-push-url`](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-push-url/):

> The hx-push-url attribute allows you to push a URL into the browser location history. This creates a new history entry, allowing navigation with the browser’s back and forward buttons. htmx snapshots the current DOM and saves it into its history cache, and restores from this cache on navigation.

This causes previous pages to just get **restored and not reloaded** and If I remove `hx-push-url`, navigation doesn't match with user's expectation. Almost all of my page navigations are with `Htmx` and I sometimes want pages to reload on navigating back. Is there a way achieve this with Htmx? Or could be that I'm misusing Htmx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTMX does not provide an official way to prevent this behavior, yet. However with a little manual work we can force HTMX to make a full page refresh. HTMX stores the page in the `localStorage` under `htmx-history-cache` key. So we can use the `htmx:pushedIntoHistory` event (~ the page has been saved to the history) to delete this key completely, forcing HTMX to make a new request to the server.

```
<script>
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:pushedIntoHistory', (evt) => {
  localStorage.removeItem('htmx-history-cache')
})
</script>
```

However, by default HTMX will make an AJAX request instead a full page reload. To force a full reload, we also need to set `refreshOnHistoryMiss` to `true`:

```
<meta name="htmx-config" content='{"refreshOnHistoryMiss":"true"}' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this:

```html
<body hx-history="false" hx-boost="true" hx-push-url="true">
```

> Set the hx-history attribute to false on any element in the current document, or any html fragment loaded into the current document by htmx, to prevent sensitive data being saved to the localStorage cache when htmx takes a snapshot of the page state.
>
> History navigation will work as expected, but on restoration the URL will be requested from the server instead of the history cache.

Source: [docs](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-history/)